# substring merge two dataframes of different sizes based on a column

Tags: python, dataframe, merge, fuzzy

I have 2 dataframes like these:

**df1**

```
Alias   seq_RNA
Hsa-Mir-133-P2-v1-5p    AGCTGGTAAAATGGAACCAAATC
Hsa-Mir-143-P1-v2-3p    TTGGTCCCCTTCAACCAGCTGT
Hsa-Mir-183-P1-v1-3p    TTTGGTCCCCTTCAACCAGCTGT
Hsa-Mir-490-3p  CAACCTGGAGGACTCCATGCTGT
Hsa-Mir-499-5p  TTAAGACTTGCAGTGATGTTTA
Hsa-Mir-163-P2-v2-3p    TTGGTCCCCTTCAACCAGCTA
Hsa-Mir-122-as-5p   TTTAGTGTGATAATGGCGTTTG
Hsa-Mir-1-P1-5p ACATACTTCTTTATATGCCCATA
```

**df2**

```
    Alias   MiRBase_ID
    Hsa-Mir-4-P1    hsa-let-133 
    Hsa-Let-7-P1c   hsa-let-7c 
    Hsa-Let-7-P1d   hsa-let-7a-2 
    Hsa-Mir-183-P1  hsa-let-183 
    Hsa-Mir-122-as  hsa-let-122 
    Hsa-Let-7-P2a3  hsa-let-7f-2
```

I want to generate a new **df3** where if there is a substring match of one of the alias between df1 and df2 it create a new column adding the corresponding MiRBase_ID, like this:

```
Alias   seq_RNA MiRBase_ID
    Hsa-Mir-133-P2-v1-5p    AGCTGGTAAAATGGAACCAAATC na
    Hsa-Mir-143-P1-v2-3p    TTGGTCCCCTTCAACCAGCTGT na
    Hsa-Mir-183-P1-v1-3p    TTTGGTCCCCTTCAACCAGCTGT hsa-let-183
    Hsa-Mir-490-3p  CAACCTGGAGGACTCCATGCTGT na
    Hsa-Mir-499-5p  TTAAGACTTGCAGTGATGTTTA na
    Hsa-Mir-163-P2-v2-3p    TTGGTCCCCTTCAACCAGCTA na
    Hsa-Mir-122-as-5p   TTTAGTGTGATAATGGCGTTTG hsa-let-122
    Hsa-Mir-1-P1-5p ACATACTTCTTTATATGCCCATA na
```

So basically when it finds a match or even a partial match (but the best match possible) of one alias in df1 in df2 it takes the MiRBase_ID and put it in the new df3. otherwhise put na if no match is found. there is no order in the 2 dataframes so each of the best match needs to be searched in the whole Alias column and df1 and df2 are of different nr of rows.

Comment: it's not really a fuzzy match here, but a substring match, no?

Comment: yes fixed thnks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to get the substring and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
import re
pattern = '|'.join(df2['Alias'].map(re.escape))

out = df1.merge(df2.drop(columns='Alias'),
                left_on=df1['Alias'].str.extract(f'({pattern})', expand=False),
                right_on=df2['Alias'], how='left').drop(columns='key_0')
```

Output:

```
                  Alias                  seq_RNA   MiRBase_ID
0  Hsa-Mir-133-P2-v1-5p  AGCTGGTAAAATGGAACCAAATC          NaN
1  Hsa-Mir-143-P1-v2-3p   TTGGTCCCCTTCAACCAGCTGT          NaN
2  Hsa-Mir-183-P1-v1-3p  TTTGGTCCCCTTCAACCAGCTGT  hsa-let-183
3        Hsa-Mir-490-3p  CAACCTGGAGGACTCCATGCTGT          NaN
4        Hsa-Mir-499-5p   TTAAGACTTGCAGTGATGTTTA          NaN
5  Hsa-Mir-163-P2-v2-3p    TTGGTCCCCTTCAACCAGCTA          NaN
6     Hsa-Mir-122-as-5p   TTTAGTGTGATAATGGCGTTTG  hsa-let-122
7       Hsa-Mir-1-P1-5p  ACATACTTCTTTATATGCCCATA          NaN
```