# Merge two dataframes in Python. The key in df2 is a substring of the key in df1

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes that need to be merged.

```
df1: {'Key1': ['abc long', 'def', 'ghi'], 'Value1': [1, 2, 3]}
df2: {'Key2': ['ab', 'dex', 'gh'], 'Value2': [4, 5, 6]}
```

The join keys, as shown above in df2, are substrings of the 'Key1' column in df1. The desired result I would like to have is as follows:
`result_df: {'Key1': ['abc long', 'ghi'], 'Value1': [1, 3], 'Value2': [4, 6]}`

The second row won't be shown in the result due to the non-matching key.

How should I do this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please see the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75097024/substring-merge-two-dataframes-of-different-sizes-based-on-a-column